# Using same jQuery more than once on a page

Tags: jquery

I want to use the following jQuery multiple times on the same page to show several different images on a page.

http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/VYbLX/

Thanks in advance!

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" />
<select id="picDD">
    <option value="1" selected>Picute 1</option>
    <option value="2">Picute 2</option>
    <option value="3">Picute 3</option>
    <option value="4">Picute 4</option>
    <option value="5">Picute 5</option>
</select>
```

```
var pictureList = [
"http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1",
"http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2",
"http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3",
"http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4",
"http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5", ];

$('#picDD').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
```

Comment: So what's the question.

Comment: Do it then! What is the problem?

Comment: The index of an array is zero-based: `pictureList[val - 1]`

Answer (score 3):

May be, I am guessing, you are not getting the right `index` values. Use the following code instead:

```
$('#picDD').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val - 1]);
});
```

Arrays start with `0` as the first index and not `1`.